# R Plotly: Move the legend title above the legends in the horizontal legend position

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I have a limitation in the window size, which requires me to have my `plotly` (converted using `ggplotly`) figures to have:

1. The legends title to be positioned above the legends (similar to `ggplot` [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656553/plot-legend-below-the-graphs-and-legend-title-above-the-legend-in-ggplot2))
2. If possible, stack the legends on top of each other in which each row contains two legends, for example.
3. Is it possible to have one legend for the two plots horizontally positioned on the bottom?

Here is my code which the plotly part needs to be modified only:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("allplots")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  output$allplots <- renderUI({
    
    test <-structure(list(
      Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
              2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      Drug = c("A", "B", "B", "C","A", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "A", "B", "B","C"), 
      Sex = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male","Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female",
              "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female"), 
      Y = c(2.192306074, 4.551912798, 1.574070652, -0.143946163, 5.144422967, 5.724705829,
            2.691617258, -3.0289955, 0.338102762, -0.558581233, -2.942620032, 1.024670497, 2.264980803, 
            2.103722883, 2.091621938, 1.535299922, 1.618399767, 0.136160703), 
      DrugSex = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L), 
                          levels = c("A,Female", "A,Male", "B,Female", "B,Male", "C,Female", "C,Male"), 
                          class = "factor"),testNo = 1:18), row.names = c(NA,-18L), class = "data.frame")

    
    Xs <- c("testNo", "Day")
    plots <- lapply(Xs, function(x){
      
      renderPlotly({

        p <-test %>% ggplot(aes_string(x = "DrugSex", y = x)) +
          geom_point(aes(color = Drug, shape = DrugSex))+ 
          labs(x = paste0("DrugSex"), y = x) + 
          scale_shape_manual(values=1:length(unique(test$DrugSex))) + 
          guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5),
                 shape = guide_legend(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5)) + 
          theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
                legend.key=element_blank() #transparent legend panel
          )
        ggplotly(p) %>%
          layout(
            legend = list(orientation = 'h', xanchor = 'center', x = .5, y = -1.5)) 
      })
    })
      
   
    fluidRow(column(width = 4, plots[[1]]),
             column(width = 4, plots[[2]]))
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the current output:

[image]

For the second part of my question, by stacking I mean an output similar like the figure below in which every row contains two legends:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
In Q1, I also want to know how I can resolve the problem with partially shown legends and titles when we have many legends, as in the picture below, Would it be useful if we could move the title of a legend to the top of the list of legends? If yes, how?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run your code, I don't get a legend for either plot.  However, I can at least answer that yes—you could move the title to the top in a roundabout way. However, since your `xaxis` title is the legend title, you could just make the legend title blank.

If the plot is narrow and the data is long, you could achieve a stacked legend, but it will change with the width of the viewing area. (You could control the size of the viewing area.)

Alternatively, it looks like Plotly added a new feature in the last few months, but Plotly for R isn't using the latest version of Plotly. You could change the dependency and control the width that way (stacking, all that jazz).

However, whether you control the plot viewing size or the legend entry size, it won't split the legends.

One legend...I know there are issues with `subplot` in Plotly and Shiny. However, it works for me here.

#### Q1

Since the `xaxis` is the legend title, you could erase the legend title.

Since I am not getting a legend at all, this also turns it on.

```
fixLeg <- function(plt){
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)
  nms <- plt$x$layout$xaxis$ticktext
  plt$x$layout$legend$title$text <- ""
  map(1:length(plt$x$data), 
      function(k) {
        plt$x$data[[k]]$name <<- nms[[k]]
        plt$x$data[[k]]$showlegend <<- TRUE
      })
  plt
}
```

I modified the call, to add `showlegend`, modify `y` in `legend` and add the call for `fixLeg()`.

```
plots <- lapply(Xs, function(x){
  renderPlotly({
    p <-test %>% ggplot(aes_string(x = "DrugSex", y = x)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = Drug, shape = DrugSex))+ 
      labs(x = paste0("DrugSex"), y = x) + 
      scale_shape_manual(values=1:length(unique(test$DrugSex))) + 
      guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5),
             shape = guide_legend(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5)) + 
      theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
            legend.key=element_blank()) #transparent legend panel
    ggplotly(p) %>% fixLeg() %>%     # <---- add legend/remove legend title
      layout(showlegend = T,
             legend = list(orientation = 'h', xanchor = 'center', 
                           x = .5, y = -.3))   # <---- changed y
  })
})
```

[image]

#### Q2

A stacked legend, whether it originated as one legend or many legends. For this, I'm going to change the Plotly dependency to the latest version of Plotly JS, I'll use a function to do that. This function will allow the parameters of `entrywidth` and `entrywidthmode` to work in R.

```
fixLeg2 <- function(plt){
  plt <- plotly_build(plt)
  # changes to dependency so that entrywidth/entrywidthmode work
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$script = "plotly-2.16.1.min.js"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$local = FALSE
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$package = NULL

  # changes to object
  nms <- plt$x$layout$xaxis$ticktext
  plt$x$layout$legend$title$text <- ""
  map(1:length(plt$x$data), 
      function(k) {
        plt$x$data[[k]]$name <<- nms[[k]]
        plt$x$data[[k]]$legendgroup <<- nms[[k]]
        plt$x$data[[k]]$showlegend <<- TRUE
      })
  plt
}
```

To make sure that Shiny goes to get the CDN from the web, you'll add something else to the user interface (`ui`). This addition requires the use of `htmltools`. The Shiny app may work without this addition. However, it will be intermittent at best.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

newDep <- htmlDependency(name = "plotly-latest",
                         version = "2.16.1",
                         src = list(href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"),
                         script = "plotly-2.16.1.min.js") 
ui <- fluidPage(
  createWebDependency(newDep),
  uiOutput("allplots")
)
```

Then with the plots, add an `entrywidth`. Additionally, change the function call for `fixLeg` to `fixLeg2`.

By the way `entrywidth` is the width in pixels of the text component of a legend entry. The symbol, dot, line, or colored part is `item` in the legend. You can control that size, too. I'm pretty sure that control is fairly new, as well.

```
plots <- lapply(Xs, function(x){
  renderPlotly({
    p <-test %>% ggplot(aes_string(x = "DrugSex", y = x)) +
      geom_point(aes(color = Drug, shape = DrugSex))+ 
      labs(x = paste0("DrugSex"), y = x) + 
      scale_shape_manual(values=1:length(unique(test$DrugSex))) + 
      guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5),
             shape = guide_legend(title.position="top", title.hjust = 0.5)) + 
      theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
            legend.key=element_blank() #transparent legend panel
      )
    ggplotly(p) %>% fixLeg2() %>%     # <------- I'm new
      layout(showlegend = T,
             legend = list(orientation = 'h', xanchor = 'center', 
                           x = .5, y = -.3, entrywidth = 100)) # <- entry width
  })
})
```

This is how it's changed:

[image]

In your question, you had specifically asked about when there is more than one legend, but your plots in this question only have one. I've taken this plot from a previous question. (Where `df` is extremely similar to `test` in this question.)

```
p <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x = DrugSex, y = Y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Drug, shape = DrugSex)) + 
  geom_segment(data = df_means, aes(x=x-0.25, xend=x+0.25, y=Mean, yend=Mean, color= 
                                      color),inherit.aes = F, show.legend = F)+
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        legend.key=element_blank() #transparent legend panel
  )
```

I have to change the call to change the dependencies a bit, because this plot isn't in Shiny. Really, I've just added one new line (`src$file = NULL`).

```
fixLeg3 <- function(plt) {
  # changes to dependency so that entrywidth/entrywidthmode work
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$file = NULL
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$script = "plotly-2.16.1.min.js"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$local = FALSE
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$package = NULL
  plt
}
```

I've added a new parameter `entrywidthmode`. This is default `pixels`. However you can use `fraction` as in a fraction of the plot. If I set it to .3 (so there's still room for the title), No matter how big I make this plot, only three legend entries are going on a single line.

```
ggplotly(p) %>% fixLeg3() %>% 
  layout(legend = list(orientation = "h", 
                       y = -.3, entrywidthmode = "fraction",
                       entrywidth = .3))
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Q3

When it comes to consolidating the legend, Plotly's `subplot` can do it for you. However, it won't do it without intervention. That's because you can select a legend item it hides or shows in the plot. You can use `legendgroups` to get around it. This will still allow entry selection by clicking on a legend item, but it will affect both plots.

To use legend grouping and have a consolidated legend, you have to designate the legend group of each trace, and you have to hide all but one trace within each legend group from the legend. Here's a simpler example. (By the way, hiding it in `ggplot` does nothing!)

```
pp1 <- pp2 <- ggplot(test,  # first plot, keep the legend
              aes(x = Drug, y = Y, color = Drug, shape = DrugSex)) +
  geom_point()

p2 <- ggplotly(pp2) # hide the legend in this plot
invisible(lapply(1:length(p2$x$data),
                 function(k) {
                   p2$x$data[[k]]$showlegend <<- FALSE # change in global
                 }))

subplot(ggplotly(pp1), p2) %>%  # put it together
  layout(showlegend = T, 
         legend = list(traceorder = "grouped", # <- make sure this is called first!!
                       orientation = "h", x = .5, xanchor = "center",
                       valign = "bottom"))
```

[image]

In Shiny, don't use `renderPlotly` to show a `subplot`. Just use `renderUI` and call `subplot` like you would in an R script.

If you find that a combined legend won't orient horizontally, make sure that `traceorder` is called before `orientation`. It *shouldn't* matter, but it does.

Comment: It would be good if you add the library(purrr) to your reply so that the map function can run without a problem. I think the last option now works best for me. However, I would like to have the axis titles as well and would appreciate it if you could help me with how to have the x and y-axis titles. Based on the user input, the number of plots may differ; therefore, having one legend for all of the subplots would be good. I think I can control the number of plots in each row by setting subplot(nrows = 2); for example, however, how should I control the vertical distance between plots?

Comment: Found the answer to the first part by adding arguments titleY = TRUE, titleX = TRUE. However, still have problems with the plot's structure and spacing to prevent the legends from overlapping the plots.

Comment: There are several things that feed into alignment and fit. The default sizing for the viewer pane and a browser are set to _fill_. Your plots will stretch to fit all space, ignoring things like `layout.xaxis.title.offset` and `layout.margin` where fill and the spacing controls conflict. To find the best fit, how are you using it? You're likely to adhere to the `browser` policy outside of Shiny--- but not within Shiny! View these settings by going to `plt$sizingPolicy` (where `plt` is the name of your plot or subplot). A number alone like `$defaultHeight` which is 400, is  400 px.

Comment: How can I combine the answers to questions 2 and 3? In some of my plots, I have many legends causing the legend titles to be printed partially on the left side of the legends of the subplot. For example can not see DrugSex,Durg but what they can see is "ugSex, ug".

Comment: Define a specific aspect ratio for each plot, ensure that `fill = FALSE` for whatever sizing policy applies and use `entrywidthmode = "fraction"`. For the `entrywidth` use a value that can't  = 1. For example, setting it to 0.3, because if there are two entries or 10 entries, it won't take up the width of the plot.  Setting it to 0.26 gives you three entries per plot width while leaving you with quite a bit left over. For 2D plots, aspect ratio is set on either `layout.xaxis` or `layout.yaxis`, using `scaleanchor` and `scaleratio`. I found an example [here](https://plotly.com/r/axes/).

Comment: In Q1, you assumed that the legend and x-axis are the same; what if they are not the same, and we still want to make the legend title appear above the legends? The problem I still have is that when we have many legends, the legend's title will be partially shown. I add a new phot in the updated of the question to better explain what my problem is

Comment: To add the legend title to the top of the legend while it's horizontal, use the x-axis title in a unique way. Let's say you've set the x-axis title to "x-axis". You could add the legend title by writing `"x-axis<br>legend title"` or if you want more space, `"x-axis<br><br>legend title"` You can use inline css styling here, as well (i.e., color, boldness, size, etc.). To change the legend title position with JS, you have to modify the SVG significantly. It would lose the ability to dynamically change with the plot size, too.